# CSS footer positioning to vertically center text when using bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cannot seem to position text on the right side of this footer:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x6La5bva/)

Basically what happens is that I need the "center" class to keep the text vertically aligned on the footer, but using the "center" class and the "text-right" class (In bootstrap) will have the text messed up. If I only use the "text-right" class, the text is on the right, but way up top.

The CSS for .center is:

```
.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;           
  top: 50%;                      
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach one - Bootstrap method [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/7pghqbjs/):

Modified HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row center">
            <p class="col-xs-9">...</p>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
                <a href="index.html">...</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Basically, just added the `container`/`row` elements and use columns. Add your custom `center` class to the `row` element.

---

Approach two [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/wb6kb75a/):

Set the display of the `footer` element to `table`, and then set the `display` of the children elements to `table-cell` and use `vertical-align: middle` for vertical centering.

```
footer {
    background: #ECECEC;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display:table;
}
footer > p,
footer > div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:20px;
}
```

---

Approach three [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yajx4L6/):

Since the height of the `footer` is fixed, an arguably hackish solution would be to set a `line-height` with a value equal to the `footer`'s height - in this case, `100px`. You would also have to swap out `text-right` for `pull-right`/`pull-left`.

---

Approach four - using your custom `center` class [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/jvucsbgu/):

```
.center {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    width:100%;
}
```

Modified HTML:

```
<p class="text-left center">...</p>
<div class="text-right center"> <a href="index.html">...</a>
```

Comment: All of these work fine on jsfiddle, but they all somehow mess up when I add "padding-left" to them.

Comment: @user3875455 I just updated a couple of the fiddles and added padding. Maybe that will help?

Comment: Any ideas why the footer will stay at the bottom of the page on load? http://jsfiddle.net/jvucsbgu/1/ scrolling all the way down will reveal the footer coveres up the content.

Comment: @user3875455 Add `html { min-height:100%; position:relative; }` [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/zvm904er/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using flex layout then this will be the perfect way and easiest way to do it

```
.center { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center; 
}
```

Awesome read about centering text : https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-perfectly-centered-text-with-flexbox--cms-27989